# Update row with check by linq2db in one atomic operation

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq2db

MS SQL database table has **timestamp** field which value changing after update row.
Before update I want to check if the row is changed from another service.

I can do it by comparing **timestamp** values from object in memory with value from database table.

Can I do it by **linq2db** in one atomic operation?

It works without checking:

```
db.Update(product);
```

These three queries do not work:

```
db.Products.Where(p => p.timestamp == product.timestamp).Update(p => p, product);
db.Products.Update(p => p.timestamp == product.timestamp, p => product );
db.Where<DB, Product, DB>(p => p.timestamp == product.timestamp).Update(product);
```

I want to execute sql-script like this:

```
update Products
set ...-- all fields
where Id = @id and Timestamp = @timestamp
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to leave an answer here, since linq2db is an awesome tool, which I would like to be more popular.

In your case you will need to set all fields of your entity separately, like this:

```
db.Products
  .Where(p => p.timestamp == product.timestamp)
  .Set(p => p.Name, product.Name)
  .Set(p => p.UnitPrice, product.UnitPrice)
  // ...
  .Update();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be awful due to the fact that we need to write as a long construction as T-SQL code, firstly. In addition, remember to update it simultaneously with changing the DB schema.

Comment: You can easily write a helper method to deal with it. The other suggestion is pull request to linq2db repo :)